# Any way to select cell in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm trying to make time table application. my `layout` is `gridview`.

My `layout` is now like this : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37032956/57445643-c2765180-728d-11e9-9f1a-52e2d93f7e9e.JPG

I can get data and draw in a line. 
But i don't know how to locate this cells in particular location.

I want to place this 4 colored text in exact location using day, start time, end time.

This is my code.

```
 public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<GridViewItem> listData;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GridviewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<GridViewItem> listData){
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position); // 수정
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridViewHolder gridViewHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, (ViewGroup) convertView, false);
            gridViewHolder = new GridViewHolder();
            gridViewHolder.subjectTitle=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            convertView.setTag(gridViewHolder);

        } else {

            gridViewHolder = (GridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        gridViewHolder.subjectTitle.setText(listData.get(position).getSub_title());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class GridViewHolder{
        TextView subjectTitle;
        // day, start_time, end_time;
    }
   }
```

Here is my grid view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnItemClickListener which correspond to the item position.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
    {
        //Selected item is at index "position".
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want the exact row of the selection, you can use your columns number, with something like

int row = position / columnsNumber

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to change my item from the beginning not when item is clicked.